# Functions Hook add_post_meta ACF Post Object

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a function in functions.php:

```
function create_whiteboard( $form_id, $post_id, $form_settings ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
'post_type' => 'whiteboard',
'post_title' => 'Whiteboard for ' . $current_user->user_firstname . ' ' . $current_user->user_lastname,
'post_status' => 'publish',
));
add_post_meta($post_id, 'project_select', $post_id, true);
}
add_action('create_whiteboard_hook', 'create_whiteboard', 10, 3 );
```

This works in that it creates a post in whiteboard post type - but it doesn't update my post object field (project_select). If I specify an ID:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'project_select', '1', true);
```

Then it does work - my question is how do I pass the ID of the post just created into this?

Answer (score 0):

The `$post_id` is overwritten by the assignment of the return value from `wp_insert_post`.

As is, the whiteboard post created is the one being decorated with the metadata and not the intended post.

You can fix this by using a different name for the variable referencing the return value from call to `wp_insert_part`.

```
function create_whiteboard( $form_id, $post_id, $form_settings ) {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $whiteboard_post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
    'post_type' => 'whiteboard',
    'post_title' => "Whiteboard for {$current_user->user_firstname} {$current_user->user_lastname",
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  ));

  add_post_meta($post_id, 'project_select', $whiteboard_post_id, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - but still not working. It is still creating the whiteboard post fine, but not assigning the other post ID to the project_select post object. I am creating a post called projects, and calling this hook from the frontend to then create the whiteboard post.

Comment: I mean update the whiteboard post type and the field project_select to the id of the newly created post type that they have just inserted. From the form they create a new post in PROJECTS. In that same form I call this hook to insert a post into WHITEBOARD. The field project_select (ACF post object) from whiteboard links it back to the projects post that was just created.

Comment: It doesnt make any difference if I flip them about either. As for the form, the user first creates a project and then I want this whiteboard created automatically. Then within whiteboard I want the project_select field updated with the post ID of the project just created.

Comment: Can you document in your question what plugin/theme your using for the whiteboard? I am concerned about finding documentation for `create_whiteboard_hook`.  Right now I doubt that arguments passed in the hook are what they should be. To be sure, what do you get when you write `echo var_dump($post_id);` before `add_post_meta`?